# Is this verse supported or contradicted by any other scripture?

Tags: shiva, yogi

In chapter 8 of Sri Shiva Rahsya, Lord Shiva says-

> 41. Having been put to sleep at the moment of creation, man begins his worldly life in the form of an inanimate thing made of space, air, fire, water or earth.  He abides in that condition for forty-two thousand lifetimes.  He then enters a state like that of dream and assumes the form of half-sentient things such as plants or trees.  Thus he passes fifteen thousand lifetimes.  In the form of insects or worms he abides for twelve thousand lives.  Nine thousand in the form of a sentient beast such as land-borne, water-borne or air-borne creatures; and six thousand lifetimes in human form.
> 42. Having thus passed through eighty-four thousand lives, man is born only three more times: once as a Yogi and twice as a God.  Then, having attained the Supreme Perfection of Heaven (Para Siddhi), he is born no more.

---

Are these statements supported or contradicted by other scriptures? If I become a Yogi, I will only live 2 other lives?

Comment: Don't take directly meanings.  There are hidden wisdom behind it.

Comment: @AkshayS What is the hidden meaning?

Comment: @ShashwatAsthana, it is hidden :)